# Scripting: Read condition written in words and converting into C - ternary operator

Tags: perl

I am new to the perl scripting. I am writing script to read excel file and put in text file in C programing syntax.

So I excel sheet I have string like below:

```
If ((Myvalue.xyz == 1) Or (Frmae_1.signal_1 == 1)) Then a = 1
else a = 0;
```

This I have to convert into:

```
a = (((Myvalue.xyz == 1) || (Frmae_1.signal_1 == 1))?1:0)
```

How this can be handled in perl?

Comment: From what I understand that should work. Here is a website with some information on that http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_conditions.htm

Comment: Here is another question on stack overflow with a similar question that might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009/why-does-the-perl-conditional-operator-not-do-what-i-expect

Comment: Not sure what are you looking for, `my $a = 1 * ($val1 == 1 || $val2 == 1);`?

Comment: @mpapec Why would you multiply by 1?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen OP wants 0|1 number as result

Comment: @mpapec The result of the boolean expression will be a number already.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen it will be `1` or empty string for boolean

Comment: It will definitely be 1 or 0 given the ternary expression, which are both numbers.

Comment: yes, but I don't use ternary and you've asked why I'm using `*1`

Comment: What you are asking is compiling one language to a different target language. This is actually quite fun, but more complex than just using a simple regex (which may admittedly work in many cases, but feels wrong for this task). Therefore, I'll post an answer in a few hours. It will cover: parsing with [Marpa::R2](http://p3rl.org/Marpa::R2::Scanless), [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) manipulation, optimization passes, compilation, and Perl OO. It won't cover [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser) theory etc. or provide a copy&paste-ready solution. Size: ~0.2kloc

Answer (score 8):

I do not think that throwing a regex at the code string would be an especially good idea.The syntax of your input doesn't look too extraordinary, so we could just parse it with Marpa, using a grammar like

```
:default    ::= action => [values]
:start      ::= StatementList
:discard    ~   ws

StatementList ::= <Expression>+ separator => <op semicolon> bless => Block

Expression ::=
        ('(') Expression (')')  assoc => group action => ::first
    |   Number                  bless => Number
    ||   Ident                  bless => Var
    ||  Expression  ('==')  Expression  bless => Numeric_eq
    ||  Expression  ('=' )  Expression  bless => Assign
    ||  Expression  ('Or')  Expression  bless => Logical_or
    ||  Conditional

Conditional ::=
        ('If') Expression ('Then') Expression
            bless => Cond
    |   ('If') Expression ('Then') Expression ('Else') Expression
            bless => Cond

Ident   ~ ident
Number  ~ <number int> | <number rat>

word    ~ [\w]+
ident   ~ word | ident '.' word
<number int> ~ [\d]+
<number rat> ~ <number int> '.' <number int>
ws      ~ [\s]+
<op semicolon> ~ ';'
```

Then:

```
use Marpa::R2;
my $grammar = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new({
    bless_package => 'Ast',
    source => \$the_grammar,
});
my $recce = Marpa::R2::Scanless::R->new({ grammar => $grammar });
$recce->read(\$the_string);
my $val = $recce->value // die "No parse found";
my $ast = $$val;
```

As soon as we have the AST, compiling it down to the C-like representation isn't overly complex. Factoring out the common assignment with an “optimization” pass can be done with a bit of thinking.

However, showing how this can be done is rather lengthy, so I put all the in-depth stuff into this [blogpost](https://lukasatkinson.de/2013/transforming-syntax/). We can then define a method that recurses through the tree and emits the C-like code, e.g.

```
package Ast::Var;
...;
sub compile { my $self = shift; $self->name } # no modification needed

package Ast::Logical_Or;
...;
sub compile {
  my $self = shift;
  # C's "||" operator, plus parens to specify precedence
  "(" . $self->l->compile . "||" . $self->r->compile . ")";
}

package Ast::Cond;
...;
sub compile {
  my $self = shift;
  return sprintf '(%s ? %s : %s)',
      $self->cond->compile,
      $self->then->compile,
      $self->else->compile;
}
```

etc. for all the other AST node types.

Answer (score 0):

The same expression is valid in Perl (modulo the access operator, that `->` in perl and not the dot. You can also do

```
a = $my_value->xyz == 1 || $frmae_1->signal_1 == 1 ? 1 : 0;
```

the `? 1 : 0` part is not even necessary since `$my_value->xyz == 1 || $frmae_1->signal_1 == 1` will return the Perl true or false values (numerically `1` and `0`, string `'1'` and `''`)...

Answer (score 0):

Say, your string is stored in `$str`. You can do the following to extract stuff from it:

```
my ($cond, $set, $then, $else) = ($str =~ /^If (.*) Then (.*?=\s+)(.*) else \2(.*);$/);
```

Now you have your condition in `$cond`, `a =` in `$set` and what should be in that variable in `$then` and `$else`.

Replace "or" and "and" in your condition

```
$cond =~ s/\sOr\s/ || /g;
$cond =~ s/\sAnd\s/ && /g;
```

and print your desired output

```
print "$set($cond ? $then : $else);
```

Those regular expressions work with your string: I got

```
a = (((Myvalue.xyz == 1) || (Frmae_1.signal_1 == 1)) ? 1 : 0)
```

but can fail if your actual strings have "Then" written as "then", will explode if your "Myvalue.xyz" in some string is "Myvalue.And" or something like that. Also this will not work if there are no spaces somewhere around `=` or `Or`. But the code can be easily modified to work with all these inputs. Be careful with regular expressions, they are powerful.